# Urlread in matlab with variables

Tags: matlab

How can I use the urlread function in matlab with variable inputs in the url address itself?

For eaxmple:
I may want to read:
`http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=22,77&sensor=true`
but instead of typing in the latitude and longitude values(22,77). I need to write variable names only in an mfile, and then call it with different values every time when running the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
base_str = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=';
read_from_mat = foo_to_read_from_mat_returns_string();
url_str = strcat(base_str,read_from_mat,'&sensor=true');

urlread url_str;
```